# How to get array values in hash using map function in Perl

Tags: perl, dictionary

I have an array of elements combined with # which I wish to put in hash , first element of that array as key and rest as value after splitting of that array elements by #
But it is not happening.

Ex:

```
my @arr = qw(9093#AT#BP 8111#BR 7456#VD#AP 7786#WS#ER 9431#BP ) #thousand of data
```

What I want is

```
$hash{9093} = [AT,AP];
$hash{8111} = [BR]; and so on
```

How we can accomplish it using map function. Otherwise I need to use for loop but I wish to use map function.

Comment: You should run your Perl code with `use strict` and `use warnings` in effect. For example: `Possible attempt to put comments in qw() list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my %hash = map { my ($k, @v) = split /#/; $k => \@v } @arr;
```

For comparison, the corresponding foreach loop follows:

```
my %hash;
for (@arr) {
   my ($k, @v) = split /#/;
   $hash{$k} = \@v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ikegami, Your answer is similar to tobyink. So, I would choose his answer as best. Thank you guys for such a fast response.

Comment: If you're going to format the code as his answer, then you'd be better off using a foreach loop!

Comment: But if you both have written the same code, only diff is variable name though I used your code. Thank you all

Answer (score 5):

Use `split` to split on '#', taking the first chunk as the key, and keeping the rest in an array. Then create a hash using the keys and references to the arrays.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr  = qw( 9093#AT#BP 8111#BR 7456#VD#AP 7786#WS#ER 9431#BP );
my %hash = map {
   my ($key, @vals) = split '#', $_;
   $key => \@vals;
} @arr;

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: Thanks Tobyink. It didn't come in my mind that we can assign and write some codes like this.

Very well done! It helped

Answer (score 2):

No effort shown in your question, but I am on a code freeze so I'll bite :)

A think that a for loop would be more idiomatic Perl here, process the elements one-by-one, split on `#` and then assign into your hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr = qw(9093#AT#BP 8111#BR 7456#VD#AP 7786#WS#ER 9431#BP );
my %h;

for my $elem ( @arr ) {
   my ($key, @vals) = split /#/, $elem; 

   $h{$key} = \@vals;
}
print Dumper \%h;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is easy:

```
%s = (map {split(/#/, $_, 2)} @arr);
```

Testing it:

```
$ cat 1.pl
my @arr = qw(9093#AT#BP 8111#BR 7456#VD#AP 7786#WS#ER 9431#BP );
%s = (map {split(/#/, $_, 2)} @arr);
foreach my $key ( keys %s )
{
  print "key: $key, value: $s{$key}\n";
}

$ perl 1.pl
key: 7456, value: VD#AP
key: 8111, value: BR
key: 7786, value: WS#ER
key: 9431, value: BP
key: 9093, value: AT#BP
```

Comment: Not quite. Does `9093 => 'AT#BP'` instead of `9093 => [ 'AT', 'BP' ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr = ('9093#AT#BP', '8111#BR', '7456#VD#AP', '7786#WS#ER', '9431#BP' );
my %h = map { map { splice(@$_, 0, 1), $_ } [ split /#/ ] } @arr;
print Dumper \%h;
```